# How to extend cell signal inside

Tags: ping, repeater, signal-strength

I have a wireless credit card machine that works off of cell towers (AT&T) is the carrier.  I can only get a signal if I take the machine outside.  How can I get a signal inside??

Answer (score 1):

Places like AT&T and Verizon will often supply a 'Booster box' for you to plug in at your location if you have bad signal. This device is sometimes free and should be able to give you the signal you will need. I'd definitely talk to AT&T and see if the booster will work with your machine first though.

Comment: The most important point with this answer is that you are resolving the issue within the framework of your provider (and by extension, your agreement with them). Buying your own repeater or in any way resolving this issue without involving your provider first is a *bad idea*.

Answer (score 1):

There are moderately-priced passive antennas for cellular frequencies, e.g. at [Alternative Wireless](http://www.alternativewireless.com/cellular-antennas.html) and at [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=cell+phone+antenna). If the credit-card machine has an antenna jack, then that would be the simplest way to increase signal strength.

This worked well for me for a wireless broadband USB device, with the magnetic-mount antenna placed on a pizza plate as a ground plane. The antenna was usable inside the building, though I could have placed it outside a window, if needed.

Comment: This is a good point, depending on the machine there may be a way to extend the range of the machine without needing a repeater.